# Laravel Eloquent skip every N th row

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a large DB, with 50000+ rows, i'm trying to get all rows but with skipping every 50 rows for example.

I tried this from Laravel documentation: Offset & Limit

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

But this will only skip the first 10 rows and get the next 5 rows. I can't find Eloquent solution to this problem.

Has anybode solve this before?

Comment: So you want to skip 50, then take a row, then skip 50 and take another row?  Are you doing this because you are concerned about the size of the table?  Are you concerned at all with how long it will take the query to run?

Comment: @user3158900 Exactly! DB is too big to be sent as a JSON to a client. I'm not concerned about how long it will take the query, since it will be cached.

Answer (score 2):

Solved using raw query:

```
return DB::select(DB::raw('
   SELECT dateTime, row1, row2
      FROM (
         SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum, dateTime, row1, row2
            FROM (
               SELECT @row :=0
            ) r, users
         ) ranked
      WHERE rownum % 50 = 0'));
```

It's much faster solution then @disf.asia suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a loop.

```
$start = 0; 
$skip  = 50;
$take  = 1;
$all = array();
do {
   $partial = User::skip($start++ * $skip)->take($take)->get();
   $all = array_merge($all, (array) $partial);
} while (count($partial) > 0);
```

this will take 1 row every 50skipped rows, so 1st, 51th, 100th ... till the end of the table

Comment: Your method is working but it takes about 20 sec for a query, that is a lot. I found a solution which takes 400ms.

Comment: Well, you said you were not concerned about the time!

Comment: It's true, 2, 3 and even 5 sec is ok. But 20 seconds is a lot for 50k rows.. Thanks anyway for your solution.